# Crystal Report Field Headers Not Auto Generating

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm using Crystal Reports 2008 and, by default, when you drag a field from the field explorer into the details section of the report, a field header gets auto generated in the page header section directly above where you placed the field.  This is how I generated several reports.

In an attempt to add a field to one of these reports, I am suddenly no longer able to get the field header to auto generate as it was before.  What setting/property could I have possibly changed to affect this behavior and how can I revert it back to the default.

Note: Even when I make a new report, I am unable to drag fields into the details field and have them appear with a field header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`File | Options... | Layout | Insert Detail Field Headings`

In the case that you have a second `details` section, adding a field to `details a` will create a field heading; adding a field to `details b` will NOT create a heading.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on vacation and don't have Crystal with me, but to change that setting you should right-click in the designer and click Default Settings. There you should be able to change the "Show Field Headings" property to a value you desire.
Also, be aware that Crystal sometimes puts the headings in a different section.